# Authentication fails on google home (oauth2)

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-home

I'm trying to connect to google home using OAuth2.0 mechanism. However, hitting with an issue where I'm not able to retrieve success message.

The failing request is - https://oauthintegrations.googleapis.com/v1/token:getForService
with the response payload as `redirectState`. I know about redirect but what is redirectState? I tried to search a bit over this one, but failed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note:I have followed all the necessary steps mentioned in doc, I can receive authorisation code, but not able to make token request to desired endpoint.

The docs are https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow and https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking.

In configuration settings we have Linking type as Oauth -> Authorization Code.

In dialog flow in Integration -> Integration Settings we have checked in for 'Sign in required' for Default Welcome Intent and have the firebase function as

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn());
});
```

according to https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking document and I am currently using API version V2.

After the auth code is received as mentioned it does not call token url, we receive this screen :

Bad response from IdP in Auth Code Exchange & what is redirect_state

The https://gala-demo.appspot.com/app#redirect_state=XXX&state=yyy&service=abc when inspected fails at https://oauthintegrations.googleapis.com/v1/token:getForService as mentioned by @rajesh with status code 400, but when this request is made through postman it return the response. Here is the body and response for the request.

Body :

```
 {
    "credential" : {
        "redirectState": "XXX"
    },
    "scopes": [],
    "gdiState": "APP_AUTH",
    "serviceId": "tapclicks-integration-adac2_dev"
}
```

RESPONSE :

```
{
   "serviceInfo": {
       "authUrl": "https://-domain-/authorization",
       "name": "tapclicks dashboard",
       "logoUrl": "https://placeholder.com/",
       "clientId": "zdqexVMaVvxIMQ7Frjwa",
       "tokenUrl": "https://-domian-/token_url",
       "privacyPolicyUrl": "https://placeholder.com/",
       "tosUrl": "https://placeholder.com/",
       "id": "tapclicks-integration-adac2_dev"
   },
   "completionInfo": {
       "appauthInfo": {
           "appauthRedirectUrl": "https://-domain-/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=zdqexVMaVvxIMQ7Frjwa&redirect_uri=https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/tapclicks-integration-adac2&scope=gmail&state=yyy",
           "appauthRedirectState": "abcxxx"
       },
       "oauthAuthorizationUrl": "https://-domain-/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=zdqexVMaVvxIMQ7Frjwa&redirect_uri=https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/tapclicks-integration-adac2&scope=gmail&state=yyy"
   },
   "gdiState": "APP_AUTH",
   "header": {}
}
```

Can you please tell if i might be making any configuration mistake or any other info you need.

Authorization Url : https://kprb95tye7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/authorization/

Token Url : https://9343j46f16.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/token_url/

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a little confused about exactly what you're doing and what "doc" you're talking about. Can you update your question to indicate what doc you're talking about and exactly what your setup and configuration is. Providing sample code, screen shots of configuration settings, logs, or anything else that will help others understand what you're doing and exactly what errors you're getting will let us help you debug the problems.

Comment: @Prisoner updated the question!

Comment: You've said you have configured it to use OAuth -> Authorization Code. Can you update the question to indicate the Authorization URL and Token URL that you've set in the "Client information" section? Those responses do not look like OAuth exchanges.

Comment: Authorisation Url : https://subdomain.amazonaws.com/authorization/
Token Url : https://subdomain.amazonaws.com/token_url/ they are like this.

Comment: @Prisoner do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I've tried looking up information about this authorization method, and couldn't find any, but it doesn't appear to be an OAuth server. If you have a reference for the auth server, I might be able to provide more information.

Comment: @Prisoner can you see the urls now?